# MYSQL:Failed to create the database connection.message from server: "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, connection

```
max_connections=512,max_used_connections=468,Threads_connected=90,Processlist=90
```

(except one remaining are in sleep mode), We are getting too many connections error regularly. If we restart Mysql then its working fine but again after some time same issue we are getting.

Comment: The connection pool is full; so, any more connections to the database are not allowed. You need to close the unnecessary/sleep connections. Also, in your code; you need to check if the result-set connections are closed after the query is performed.

Comment: can i decrease the wait_timeout value and increase the max connections value. And how can i save these changes permanently ,once i restart the server all values becomes as default values.how can i fix this.

Comment: IMHO please check your code; it is better to fix issues in code for closing statements once the query is run. Reducing wait_timeout value will allow MYSQL to terminate the connections when idle. You can try to reduce it and check.